# Creating An Automatic Employee of Relationship At Signup

Tags: civimember

When someone signs up on behalf of an organization in Civicrm two records are created: one for the individual and one for the organization but no Employee of relationship is created.This relationship has to be added manually. How can one cnfigure Civicrm such that when an individual signs up on behalf of an organization an automatic 'Employee of' relationship is automatically created.

Answer (score 3):

When someone makes a contribution on behalf of an organization, the relationship is automatically is created. I just tested this on my local sandbox, using the default "On behalf of Organization" profile.

Please replicate the relationship not being created at a [CiviCRM demo](https://civicrm.org/demo) and update your question, indicating that you were able to reproduce there.

Comment: Thanks. You were right. I noticed that an automatic relationship is created. But i would have loved a situatio where when the person who signs up on behalf of the organization logs in the organization dashboard is displayed rather than the individual. Or is there any way that this can be achived?

Comment: What relationship is best to use in a scenario where an individual signs up on behalf of an organization but the organization is actually the Member? Is it the Employer of or Employee of relationship type? 

I want the Organization to be the primary Member.

Comment: Please ask this as another question (i see you've already done that) - and accept my answer for this question (if you agree of course)